# Why deleted monogo collection document when it is save operation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Suppose, i have,

`User data= new User(id=6505ab53cd6fb759, name=Hello, age=30, address=xyz`);

and one edited list like:

```
[User(id=6505ab53cd6fb759, name=Hello, age=40, address=xyz`)]
```

& mongo collection name 'userInfo'

Following code is the implemented code:

```
public Boolean updateUserInfo(User[] editedData) {
    try {

        String collectionName = "userInfo";

        for (User data : editedList) {
            String objIdStr = data.getId();
            ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(objIdStr);
            // fetch the document
            Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
            User dBData = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class,
                    collectionName);
            
            User currentObj = dBData;

            // Here some not written code,but have to write later

            mongoTemplate.save(data, collectionName);
      }
```

}

In above code inside the for loop **'data'** contains edited data and **'dBData'** contains current data which not yet changed, after save operation dBData of corresponding **'id'** in **'userInfo'** collection will be updated with **'age'=40**

But, instead of update document it delete that document from **'userInfo'** collection.

Why this abnormal thing happening? And what is the solution how can i prevent delete when run save operation?

Comment: Do you have a snippet of code we can run that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Joe, please checke. I added the implemented code

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `save` instead of `update`?  Also, that code snippet seems to be retrieving the document in `dbData` but saving `data` is that correct?

Comment: Actually, i am not sure which field's data is modified or edited, any of fields can be modified that's why i am using 'save' operation.what is the problem it causes when using 'save' operation?